# Turning Off Error messages locally

Tags: warning-messages

I'm trying to turn `Off` an error in an expression.

```
myFunction[x_] = 1/x
myFunction2[x_] = Quiet[1/x]  (*1/x*)
myFunction[0]
myFunction2[0]
```

I do not want to use `:=`, I also do not want to Globally turn Off this error. I want it using `=` such that it looks like:

```
myFunction3[x_] = TurnedOffError[1/x]  (*TurnedOffError[1/x]*)
myFunction3[0]
```

Comment: It won't work on subexpressions, though: `a=3;myfunction2[x_] = a + Unevaluated@Quiet[1/x]` will evaluate `a` on assignment, but will not evaluate `1/x` on calling the function, but instead give (when calling with argument `0`) the result `3+Unevaluated[Quiet[1/0]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an attempt to answer the question exactly as posed, because generally speaking I don't consider it a good idea to subvert *Mathematica*'s evaluation process (e.g. by reaching up the stack and rewriting definitions based on their RHS before they evaluate) just to satisfy arbitrary syntactical preferences.

A better way, if you just want to stop `Quiet` from evaluating when the definition is made and before the message is actually going to be produced, is to `Block` it:

```
Block[{Quiet}, myFunction3[x_] = Quiet[1/x, Power::infy]] (* -> 1/x *)

myFunction3[0] (* -> ComplexInfinity [with no messages] *)
```

Something that works more similarly to what is described in the question, and still without requiring any awful hacks, is the following:

```
TurnedOffError /: HoldPattern[
  lhs_ = TurnedOffError[rhs_, msg : _MessageName | {___MessageName} | PatternSequence[]]
 ] := lhs = Unevaluated@Quiet[rhs, msg];

myFunction3[x_] = TurnedOffError[1/x, Power::infy] (* -> 1/x *)

myFunction3[0] (* -> ComplexInfinity [with no messages] *)
```

But this, of course, only works when `TurnedOffError` appears directly at level 1 inside `Set`.