# Function with zero or one arguments

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, argument-patterns

Is there a neat way to define a function with a single optional argument that defaults to an empty sequence? For example, suppose I want to define a wrapper for `RandomReal` that allows zero or one arguments:

```
myRandom[] := RandomReal[];
myRandom[x_] := RandomReal[x];
```

I can see two more compact ways of doing this. The first is to allow any number of arguments and then check whether we have zero or one:

```
myRandom[x___] := RandomReal[x] /; Length[{x}] ≤ 1;
```

and the other is to use a default argument of `Sequence[]`, wrapped with `Hold`:

```
myRandom[x_:Hold[Sequence[]]] := ReleaseHold[RandomReal[x]];
```

But neither of these seems very neat, and might be problematic or inefficient in some (more realistic) cases. Is there a conventional and/or neat way of doing this sort of thing?

Comment: What about `myRandom[x___] := RandomReal[x]`?

Comment: @YvesKlett OP doesn't want  `myRandom[1, 2, 3]` to pass through.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for the tip! I asked for a neat way of doing it, and you provided one. But I agree that OleksandrR.'s is neater.

Comment: Related: [(29208)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29208)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)'s request:

The [other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47834) is a reasonable solution if we take the question at face value and assume that the default value of `Sequence[]` is strictly required. Of course, it might (often) be the case in practice that we would rather have nothing at all, in place of an empty sequence, or that we would prefer not have to use a `Hold*` attribute. Some functions we might call could have `SequenceHold`, for example, and may not respond well to receiving `Sequence[]` as an argument.

An alternative is to use a pattern containing, well, `Alternatives`. For instance:

```
ClearAll[myRandom];
myRandom[x_ | PatternSequence[]] := RandomReal[x];

Trace[myRandom[]]
(* -> {myRandom[], RandomReal[], 0.492105} *)

Trace[myRandom[5]]
(* -> {myRandom[5], RandomReal[5], 1.52175} *)
```

As we see, `Sequence[]` is not introduced anywhere in the process.

We can also use this to impose restrictions on acceptable values for `x` (e.g., `x_Integer`, or `x : {__Integer}`) for which `Sequence[]` might not be a match. For an application, see [this recent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46831).

#### Footnote

The documentation is not clear on which of `x_ | PatternSequence[]` or `x : _ | PatternSequence[]` is more correct (if either is) with respect to the ultimate value assigned to `x` by the pattern matcher. Functionally, they are equivalent. But, in principle, any value might be assigned to a pattern that doesn't match, so there could be a theoretical argument to prefer the latter form.

Answer (score 6):

There are several different ways to produce this behavior.

#### Repeated

Perhaps the most direct way is to use [`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Repeated.html):

```
foo[x : Repeated[_, {0, 1}]] := bar[x]

foo[]
foo[1]
foo[1, 2]
```

> ```
> bar[]
> bar[1]
> foo[1, 2]
> ```

#### PatternSequence

Oleksandr already posted one method that I like:

```
ClearAll[foo]

foo[x_ | PatternSequence[]] := bar[x]
```

The pattern `PatternSequence[]` will match a non-existent argument.  Key here is that if `x_` does not match (and [`Alternatives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Alternatives.html) moves on to the next attempt) `x` *vanishes* from the right-hand side; or if you prefer it behaves (for the most part) as if it is replaced with `Sequence[]`.  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44084/121) of mine for more examples of and uses for this behavior.  To further illuminate this method note that this also works:

```
ClearAll[foo]

foo[x_ | Repeated[_, {0}]] := bar[x]
```

Also, if you want (or would allow) multiple arguments to `foo` to return as `bar[]` you could use:

```
ClearAll[foo]

foo[x_ | ___] := bar[x]

foo[]
foo[1]
foo[1, 2]
```

> ```
> bar[]
>
> bar[1]
>
> bar[]
> ```

#### Default

For the example you gave perhaps the most canonical is to use [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) and [`Default`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Default.html) (as Kuba showed), which works because [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html) has the [`SequenceHold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SequenceHold.html) attribute.  This also results in a clean primary definition:

```
ClearAll[foo]

Default[foo] = Sequence[];

foo[x_.] := bar[x]
```

Note that `Sequence[]` remains unevaluated in the `Default` definition:

```
?foo
```

> ```
> Global`foo
>
> foo[x_.] := bar[x]
>
> Default[foo] = Sequence[]
> ```

See [A question about two ways to use Default](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45729/121) to better understand `Default`.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `HoldFirst` `Attribute`:

```
ClearAll[myRandom]
SetAttributes[myRandom, HoldFirst]; 
myRandom[x_: Sequence[]] := RandomReal[x];
```

Another way with `Default`:

```
ClearAll[myRandom]
Default[myRandom] = Sequence[];
myRandom[x_.] := RandomReal[x];
```

Comment: I think this is a reasonable solution if we take the question at face value and assume that the default value of `Sequence[]` is strictly required. Of course, it might be the case in practice that we would rather have nothing at all, in place of an empty sequence, or that we would rather not have the `Hold*` attribute. In that case one can use `x_ | PatternSequence[]` as the pattern.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I think you should post this as an answer. I don't know why I always forget the `PatternSequence`. Imo it is the best solution.